# update the maximum value of ttk.Progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter

I am struggling with a seemingly simple problem: I want to be able to update the maximum value of a progress bar in `tkinter` by manually changing the value of an entry. What happens is that the initial value, 100, does not change. OK, I thought that by invoking `set` in the method `count` I would be able to update the maximum value. It didn't work. What is the problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

class Window():    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.configure()
        self.create_widgets()

    def configure(self):
        self.master.title('Progress bar')
        self.master.minsize(height=100, width=500)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.progress = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.number = tk.StringVar()
        self.number.set('100')
        self.max = tk.IntVar()
        self.max.set(eval(self.number.get()))

        b1 = tk.Button(self.master, text='Count!', command=self.count)
        b1.pack()
        e1 = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.number, width=5)
        e1.pack()

        p = ttk.Progressbar(self.master, orient='horizontal', length=200, mode='determinate', variable=self.progress, value=1, maximum=self.max.get())
        p.pack()        

    def count(self):
        self.max.set(eval(self.number.get()))
        for i in range(eval(self.number.get())):
            sleep(0.01)
            print(i)
            self.progress.set(i)
            self.master.update()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did the code throw any errors?

Comment: You called `self.max.get()` during the creation of the progress bar; that gives you a specific value (always 100, since the user has had no chance to change it yet), that value isn't going to magically change later because the var it originally came from has changed.  Unfortunately, the Progressbar doesn't support any way of specifying its maximum by way of a var, you're going to need to save a reference to the widget and explicitly set its maximum yourself.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley By "didn't work" I mean that the maximum value did not update. The code threw no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're struggling probably because you've overcomplicated the issue. Why do you use 3 separate Variable classes when you need *none*? Currently what happens is you create a progress bar with a static maximum of 100, and then you're changing how long to progress in that window by setting the entry's value.

Here's a minimal example that updates the maximum value of progress bar:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


class RestartableProgress(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.max_input = tk.Entry(self)
        self.restart_button = tk.Button(self, text="Restart",
                                                        command=self.restart)
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self)
        self.max_input.pack()
        self.restart_button.pack()
        self.progressbar.pack()


    def restart(self):
        self.progressbar['value'] = 0
        self.progress()


    def progress(self):
        max_val = self.max_input.get()
        if max_val:
            self.progressbar['maximum'] = int(max_val)
            if self.progressbar['value'] < self.progressbar['maximum']:
                self.progressbar['value'] += 1
                self.after(10, self.progress)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    rp = RestartableProgress(root)
    rp.pack()
    tk.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I didn't realize the solution could be this simple. Thanks for the answer!